# Join columns from the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

So, I have this dataframe and some columns are divided like 'Q7_part_1', 'Q7_part_2'... but they are all from the same question.

What I'm trying to do is: combine these columns in one column and exclude the nan.
I tried doing `df = df[['Q7_Part_1', 'Q7_Part_2'...]].agg(','.join ,axix=1)` also tried `df['Q7'] = df['Q7_Part_1'].map(str) + df['Q7_Part_2'].map(str)...]` but this one just joined all of then including the nan values. what else can I do?

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jliz5.png)

Comment: sample data will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one key part - `dropna()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ "question":["q1","q2","q3"],'Q7_part_1':["Q1 part 1","Q2 part 1", np.nan], 'Q7_part_2':["Q1 part2",np.nan,"Q3 part 2"]})

df.assign(Q7=df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if "part" in c]].apply(lambda s: ",".join(s.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1))
```

|  | question | Q7_part_1 | Q7_part_2 | Q7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | q1 | Q1 part 1 | Q1 part2 | Q1 part 1,Q1 part2 |
| 1 | q2 | Q2 part 1 | nan | Q2 part 1 |
| 2 | q3 | nan | Q3 part 2 | Q3 part 2 |